# CakePHP custom select

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

How can I do a select like this in cakePHP 3?

```
SELECT v.* 
from 
    user u, residents r, user_has_vehicles uv, vehicles v
where
    u.id = r.user_id
    and u.id = uv.user_id
    and uv.vehicle_id = v.id
    and r.residencial_id = 1
```

It returns just records from vehicles that has residencial_id = 1:

```
17  Renault Logan   Prata   EDS1234
```

I did something like:

```
$users = $this->User->find()
                        ->select(['id'])
                        ->matching('Residents', function ($q) {
                                return $q
                                ->select(['user_id'])
                                ->where(['Residents.residencial_id' => 1]);
                        })
                        ->contain(['UsersHasVehicles.Vehicles']);
```

But it return much more data than I need.

Comment: If you do not need the fileds from the associated model use `innerJoinWith` instead of `matching`.

http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#using-innerjoinwith

or if you really need use raw sql described here: http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/database-basics.html#running-select-statements

Comment: Thanks @rrd, it worked using raw sql for while.